# Detect line endings in current buffer, substitute all line endings depending on result

Tags: gvim, buffers, autocmd

In GVIM, I'd like to save the current file with either \r\n or \n line endings. Depending on the opened file, the appropriate line endings should be chosen automatically. I had a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79827/make-vim-act-as-notepad-on-mixed-line-endings but it doesn't quite do what I want.

My preferred behavior would be:

- If the file in the current buffer contains NO carriage returns (\r), save the whole file with line feed (\n) line endings
- If the file in the current buffer contains ANY carriage returns, save the whole file with \r\n line endings

However, I can't get quite this behavior. My current `.vimrc` looks like this:

```
" Some settings in my .vimrc that may be important
set encoding=utf-8
set list
set ffs=unix
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin


" My current status
function! CorrectLineEndings()
    " Carriage return
    let @g = "^M"
    " Testing for carriage return - doesn't work
    if match(getreg('<reg>'),@g) == @g
        " convert to \r\n line endings -> HOW?
    else
        " convert to \n line endings
        :%s/\r//g<CR>
    endif
endfunction
autocmd BufWriteCmd *.* call CorrectLineEndings()
```

There are two problems with this code - the testing for existing \r endings doesn't work and I'm not sure how to replace all line endings with \r\n.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure Vim does this mostly automatically (I rarely have to worry about it, and having edited some `ff=dos` files recently I noticed the correct line endings were used)

Comment: For me the problem is, when I open a file with Windows line endings. Then, when I press Enter in insert mode, it will insert only \n. So at the end, I'd need to insert \r manually in every line...

Comment: +1 to D. Ben Knoble's comment. I'd also add that changing `ffs` default value is likely to mess the automagic behaviour of Vim.. Otherwise, I'd have listened `FileRead` event to set `ff` accordingly -- in case the default behaviour didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick replies! Indeed I can confirm that without setting ffs everything works as expected. However, I explicitly set this so that vim indicates to me if line endings are \r\n or just \n. This is important for me since I work in Linux and Windows in parallel.

How would you make the decision in `FileRead` what line endings there are? With a `match` as indicated above or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convert on reading

Try this:

```
set fileformats=unix,dos

augroup correct_endings
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead * call CorrectEndings()
augroup END

function! CorrectEndings()
  if &fileformat != 'dos' && search('\r$', 'cnw')
    set fileformat=dos
    %s/\r$
  endif
endfunction
```

This uses Vim's built in detection for all normal files, and then performs a search to check for files with mixed line endings, saving them as dos and then removing the excess carriage returns.

### Convert on save

I include the current file's `'fileformat'` in my `'statusline'` so I can easily check what line endings the current file has without seeing `^M`s in the buffer. However, you've indicated in the comments that you specifically want to edit Windows-format files with `'fileformat'` set to `unix`, so the carriage returns are visible *in the file*.

You can achieve the above like the below:

```
set ffs=unix

augroup correct_endings
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePre * call CorrectEndings()
augroup END

function! CorrectEndings()
  if search('\r$', 'cnw')
    execute "g/\\v(\\r)@<!$/norm!A\<C-V>\<C-M>"
  endif
endfunction
```

This means that you always edit in `ff=unix` mode, but converts the line endings with a `:global` command if any `CRNL` endings are detected on save.

The global command looks a little hairy, but it's actually not *that* complicated:

```
g/\\v(\\r)@<!$/norm!A\<C-V>\<C-M>
g/            /                    # For every line where
  \\v                              # (using very magic)
             $                     # the end of the line
          @<!                      # is not preceded by
     (\\r)                         # a carriage return
               norm!               # Run the normal mode command
                    A              # to append at the end of the line
                     \<C-V>\<C-M>  # A literal carriage return character
```

Comment: @Lvn If you like the sound of the convert on read solution, but you really want dos line endings to be indicated *inline in the buffer*, then one way you can do this is to set `'list'` and something like `'listchars=eol:M'` but only when `&ff=='dos'`. I just tried this, and with appropriate highlighting to distinguish the `list` characters from the buffer contents, it works pretty well.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your effort! The second solution works like a charm - this is exactly what I wanted to do. I prefer this kind of line ending visualization since this looks like Notepad++ (which I worked extensively with in the past). Thanks also for the detailed explanation! It is very much appreciated.